# Wrong type of credentials for creating tuning model in quickstart

Tags: python, machine-learning-model, palm-api

I am trying to set up a tuning model for Palm api.

It requires authorization so I am following the [Oauth quick start](https://developers.generativeai.google/tutorials/oauth_quickstart)

I have configured the consent screen and created the desktop app credetials as stated in the guilde.

> Click Application type > Desktop app.

```
{
  "installed": {
    "client_id": "[REDACTED].googleusercontent.com",
    "project_id": "[REDACTED]",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_secret": "[REDACTED]",
    "redirect_uris": [
      "http://localhost"
    ]
  }
}
```

When I run the code found in [tuning QuickStart python](https://developers.generativeai.google/tutorials/tuning_quickstart_python)

```
import google.generativeai as palm
import os

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'C:\Development\FreeLance\machineLearning\GaTraining\creds.json'

def check_for_existing_tuned_models():
    print('Available base models:', [m.name for m in palm.list_models()])


# Press the green button in the gutter to run the script.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    check_for_existing_tuned_models()
```

I get the following error.

> The file C:\Development\FreeLance\machineLearning\GaTraining\creds.json does not have a valid type. Type is None, expected one of ('authorized_user', 'service_account', 'external_account', 'external_account_authorized_user', 'impersonated_service_account', 'gdch_service_account').

Which implies to me that it requires a service account authorization which is completely opposite of what the tutorial says i should use.

How do I authorize to palm api to create my own tuning model?

Note:

Creating a service account does work. I just dont understand why the tutorial says to use Oauth2 and configure the consent screen.   Which one should i use a service account or oauth2.

Answer (score 0):

In the tutorial you linked, it uses `gcloud` to convert the downloaded token to usable credentials. It looks like you have skipped that step here.

Check out the [oauth guide](https://developers.generativeai.google/tutorials/oauth_quickstart#manage_credentials_yourself_python) for the way to do this manually, using `Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)`.

Comment: seems like a strange way of doing it if you can just use a service account to start with and it works.   Why mess with the oauth at all?

Comment: Re: why - MakerSuite doesn't (yet) have a way to transfer ownership or to share tuned models. Using a service account works if you both create and consume the model with the same account, but if you are coming from MakerSuite, you need to be able to authenticate as the same human user.

Re: just use service account - this is good feedback, thank you. I'll see what I can do to the docs, or if you're up for helping, [this is the doc](https://github.com/google/generative-ai-docs/blob/main/site/en/tutorials/tuning_quickstart_python.ipynb).

Comment: Okay but all of the samples for palm api say to use the api key.   When I tried to use the tuned model with my api key i couldn't because it didn't have access.   I had to add the service account to my call to palm.   You may also want to consider if you will need to verfiy the app using Oauth2 consent screen for a single developer seams silly.  (just my 2 cents)